# How do Sendgird's tracking mechanisms work?

Tags: sendgrid

Does anyone know how Sendgrid tracks email deliveries, junk folder designation, and email opens?  The click tracking is pretty obvious, but the others leave me a bit perplexed.  I'm assuming that if the email doesn't bounce they track it as delivered? Are they using web beacons for opens? If so, that doesn't seem too reliable.

Comment: Prob using the 1x1 pixel graphic trick to track as opened/delivered. Image links back to their server, and they can tell if someone opens the image using an id they supply. Not sure about the marked as junk.

Comment: As per http://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/open_tracking.html, "... adds an invisible image at the end of the email which can track e-mail opens."

Comment: Right, AKA a web beacon.  Which doesn't work if the email client blocks images by default - hence the lack of reliability I mentioned.  I didn't know if they were doing something in addition to this.

Comment: no knowing how they work, My guess is part of it web[bugs, beacons] for the low hanging fruit, Monitoring of FBLs [Feed Back Loops] with the major ISPs.  Perhaps contracting with places like Return Path that have deals with ISPs, accounts etc, to check Inbox placement, junk folder status, etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can software like Return Path or SendGrid know how many emails reached inbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545918/how-can-software-like-return-path-or-sendgrid-know-how-many-emails-reached-inbox)

Comment: Yes, that answer looks relevant.  TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Delivered means the receiving server has accepted receipt of the message at the SMTP level. It makes not claims as to the final destination of the message (Inbox, Promotions, Junk, Spam).

2: There's no way for a sender to know that a receiver has "bulked" a message, since the receiver doesn't send that information back. There are companies (such as Return Path) that partner between senders and receivers to provide aggregate Inboxing data, but nothing at the message level.

3: Opens are defined from the 1x1 pixel image. As you point out, they're limited to the reader displaying images, but I'm not sure of another way to do this. I encourage senders to design messages in such a way to encourage the reader to show images, though you don't want to force it. Also, these days Gmail pre-loads all images, which inflates their open rate.

Comment: Yep, only issue w/ Gmail is their image caching can impact open rates http://blog.mailchimp.com/how-gmails-image-caching-affects-open-tracking/

Comment: True. So you'll have inflated initial opens, and deflated subsequent opens, since their servers won't query each image more than once.