# How to get send results from SendGrid back to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I have been successfully using the Email class to send emails with my rails app through heroku/sendgrid. However, I would like to save the stats (opens, clicks) back to my application. Is this possible?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545918/how-can-software-like-return-path-or-sendgrid-know-how-many-emails-reached-inbox

Comment: Unrelated to the above, but thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about E-Mail tracking and has nothing to do with Rails or Sendgrid

Answer (score 2):

You can get your stats via [API calls](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html) or you can setup the [event webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to have them posted to your server.